# Python Pulp objective function calculation error

Tags: python, linear-programming, minimization, pulp

I am a beginner in PuLP and currently I am developing a model that would assist in sizing a solar power system given the hourly energy load and the yield of a solar power system of a given size. The output of the program is governed by the following lines of code:

```
print("Ideal PV size",x.varValue/10, "Total electricity cost in a day", round(newElecCost,2),". In comparison to", round(oldElecCost,2))
for n in hoursOfDay:
    print(n, "had consumption", load[n]/10, "kWh generation", round(generation[n]/10,2),"kWh grid usage was", (vars1[n].varValue)/10, "kWh exported", (vars2[n].varValue)/10,"kWh",)

print("objective function using value(prob.objective) is",value(prob.objective))
print("objective function using the actual formula is", lpSum([vars1[a].varValue* tariff[a] for a in hoursOfDay]) + lpSum([generation[a] * x.varValue * 0.2 * 0.1 * 0.01 for a in hoursOfDay]) - lpSum([vars2[a].varValue*0.006 for a in hoursOfDay]))
```

The objective function used in the program is below.The objective is a minimisation problem.

```
prob += lpSum([vars1[a]* tariff[a] for a in hoursOfDay]) + lpSum([generation[a] * x * 0.2 * 0.1 * 0.01 for a in hoursOfDay]) - lpSum([vars2[a]*0.006 for a in hoursOfDay])
```

Which is the same as the formula written in the last print function of the output code.

However, when I do run the program, the output is the following:

```
Ideal PV size 8.0 Total electricity cost in a day 37.2 . In comparison to 46.01
1 had consumption 5.0 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 5.0 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
2 had consumption 5.2 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 5.2 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
3 had consumption 5.8 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 5.8 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
4 had consumption 9.0 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 9.0 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
5 had consumption 10.5 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 10.5 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
6 had consumption 12.0 kWh generation 0.8 kWh grid usage was 11.2 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
7 had consumption 18.0 kWh generation 2.4 kWh grid usage was 15.6 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
8 had consumption 16.2 kWh generation 3.36 kWh grid usage was 12.9 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
9 had consumption 6.7 kWh generation 4.32 kWh grid usage was 2.4 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
10 had consumption 5.5 kWh generation 6.24 kWh grid usage was 0.0 kWh exported 0.7 kWh
11 had consumption 9.0 kWh generation 7.2 kWh grid usage was 1.8 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
12 had consumption 8.5 kWh generation 7.84 kWh grid usage was 0.7 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
13 had consumption 4.3 kWh generation 7.84 kWh grid usage was 0.0 kWh exported 3.5 kWh
14 had consumption 9.1 kWh generation 7.84 kWh grid usage was 1.3 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
15 had consumption 5.8 kWh generation 6.56 kWh grid usage was 0.0 kWh exported 0.7 kWh
16 had consumption 3.4 kWh generation 5.28 kWh grid usage was 0.0 kWh exported 1.8 kWh
17 had consumption 3.4 kWh generation 4.0 kWh grid usage was 0.0 kWh exported 0.6 kWh
18 had consumption 15.0 kWh generation 1.6 kWh grid usage was 13.4 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
19 had consumption 19.0 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 19.0 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
20 had consumption 18.2 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 18.2 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
21 had consumption 5.1 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 5.1 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
22 had consumption 4.0 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 4.0 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
23 had consumption 3.1 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 3.1 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
24 had consumption 3.1 kWh generation 0.0 kWh grid usage was 3.1 kWh exported 0.0 kWh
objective function using value(prob.objective) is 43.290000000000006
objective function using the actual formula is 47.2068
```

As you can see, the energy balance in each time step seems to be working as intended as load + export is balanced by generation + grid usage. But the difference in objective function using prob.objective and the actual formula is the one that I am not sure why about.

Happy to hear your thoughts to why this is happening. Thanks,

**The way I created my variables are:

X is the variable I have set for sizing the solar power system.

Load, generation and tariff are all defined lists with named indices.

vars1 is the variable to determine how much electricity is still used from the grid after solar generation.

vars2 determines how much excess solar power is sent to the grid.

Comment: Do you get the same results using sum instead of lpSum to calculate the objective?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes both of the functions do yield the same results, although I am starting to wonder whether it is to do with any codes I had between prob.solve and the final print functions.

Comment: Also did you check the status of your problem as it may be infeasible